# Is there any way easy to use eg. 50 or more values in queries , since manually putting values in query is time consuming

Tags: query

Is there any way easy to use multiple data (eg. 50 values) in queries import from some excel , since manually putting values in query is very tedious and time consuming.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: ... and what host language?

Comment: Is this data regular (may be generated) or random (must be set value-by-value)?